# How to download artifact from Azure Artifact using Jenkins?

Tags: azure, jenkins

I have a CI CD process in an azure pipeline that collects mobile app artifacts. I also need to pick up these ready-made artifacts using Jenkins. How to do it?

Comment: I also would like to know if there are means( like ..any plugin) in Jenkins system to pull files that are available in an azure artifactory . any inputs are highly appreciated